# Duplicated triangles in medit file when using 3D mesh generation from Cgal

Tags: mesh, cgal

I am using cgal 4.8.1 to construct a 3D mesh from an implicit functions following the example from the Doc: http://doc.cgal.org/4.8.1/Mesh_3/index.html#title27

So far so good, everything works except that every triangle in the medit file is duplicated. The vertices and tetrahedra are unique. Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in the output_to_medit() method from CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h.

Thanks in advance.

Here a short part from the .mesh file with duplicated triangle entries (and yes they come sorted right away):

```
MeshVersionFormatted 1
Blockquote
Dimension 3
Vertices
5411
0.99963637682994799 -0.59041535472371098 -0.8075507050576104 1

0.52007546316605269 -1.2627393538786686 -0.36744045168512651 1
1.5605181302930933 -0.29911557239384523 0.15324871097171805 1
...
Triangles
6104
206 594 1173 1
206 594 1173 1
135 693 636 1
135 693 636 1
3838 30 866 1
3838 30 866 1
...
Tetrahedra
28314
1223 2728 133 1211 1
2813 4584 49 944 1
1229 4075 4540 2385 1
1296 3788 1857 3761 1
```

Comment: That is surprising. Can you please poste a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem occurs even when I use the code from the cgal documentation. I didn't change anything. http://doc.cgal.org/4.8.1/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2mesh_two_implicit_spheres_with_balls_8cpp-example.html
So just use this one to try. thanks

Comment: I can confirm that behavior, with the current `master` version of CGAL. I will investigate.

Comment: Okay thanks, let me know if you have any news.